# Whats the best way to center a form that's relative, the inputs inside float left and contains images

Tags: html, css, forms

I'm making a form which has little images in them that is either a tick or cross. I want these to appear that they are in the text box so to do this I have added it to the form. This site is a mobile site so I want the form to be centered on what ever sized screen and the images to always be in the same place. My method at the moment feels quite messy and works on small screens unless I actually look at in on the phone then its a mess! So whats the best way to do this? Here was my stab at it

```
html 
        <div class="formContainer">
        <form action="contact.php" method="post" class="ajax" id="contactForm">
            <div class="input">
                <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="Name" id="name">
                <div class="validation"> 
                <img src="check.svg" class="imageValidation" id="nameImage">      
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="input">
                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email" id="email">
                <div class="validation"> 
                <img src="check.svg" class="imageValidation" id="emailImage"> 
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="input">
                <select name="subject" id ="subject">
                <option value="1">Subject</option>
                <option value="Private Hire">Private Hire</option>
                <option value="Lost Items">Lost Items</option>
                <option value="Work For Us"> Work For Us</option>
                <option value="Other">Other</option>
                </select>
                <div class="validation"> 
               <img src="check.svg" class="imageValidation" id="subjectImage"> 
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="input" id="message">
                <textarea name="message" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
                <div class="validation"> 
                <img src="check.svg" class="imageValidation" id="messageImage"> 
               </div>
            </div>
        <input name="robotest" type="text" id="robotest">
        <div class="input">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
        </div>
        </form>
<p id="emailConfrimation"> Email Sent </p>
    </div>
```

the css:

```
.formContainer{
    height: 90%;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

form{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}


.input{
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    margin-top: 5%;
}

input{
    float: left;
    width: 99.9%;
    height: 100%;
    text-indent: 8%;
    background-color: #dedede;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    color: #3a3a3a;
    font-size: 1em;
    border: none;
    -webkit-border-radius:0; 
    border-radius:0;
}

select{
    float: left;
    width: 99.9%;
    height: 100%;
    text-indent: 8%;
    background-color: #dedede;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    color: #3a3a3a;
    font-size: 1em;
    border: none;
    -webkit-border-radius:0; 
    border-radius:0;
}

textarea{
    float: left;
    width: 98%;
    height: 100%;
    text-indent: 8%;
    background-color: #dedede;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    color: #3a3a3a;
    font-size: 1em;
    border: none;
    -webkit-border-radius:0; 
    border-radius:0;
    resize:none;    
}

input[type='submit']{
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #bf3737;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
   -moz-appearance:    none;
   appearance:         none;
   -webkit-border-radius:0; 
   border-radius:0;
   border: none;
   color: #ffffff;
   font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
   font-size: 1.5em;
}

.validation{
    float: left;
    width: 0.01%;
    position: relative;
    right: 20%;
    top: 0.5em;

}
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this is the best way to put your div at the center:

```
#your_div {margin:0 auto;}
```

but if you want that your div be exactly center horizontally and vertically , you should do this:

```
#main_div {position:relative}
#main_div #your_div {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-50px;  */half of your div height*/
    right:50%;
    margin-right:-70px;  */half of your div width*/
}
```